# If I buy another disc copy of a game, will my save files for it still be there?

Tags: the-witcher-3

My *Witcher 3 Wild Hunt* disc for Xbox one is not working. If I buy another disc copy of the game, will my progress and DLC be saved?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.** Save files for the Xbox One are saved online through cloud storage, meaning they can even be accessible on separate consoles.

More information can be found on the [Microsoft support page](http://support.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-one/games/cloud-game-saves-faq).

Answer (score 2):

Save games are not tied to the specific disc. As long as you retain the save files, you will be able to continue using them.

### Console

On Xbox One and PlayStation 4, your save games are saved to the console, under your user account. Providing you are signed in to the same account, and use a new copy of the game, you will still be using your old save data.

- This includes changing from a physical copy of the game to a digitally downloaded copy.
- Region free, as mentioned by @Nolonar, **does not exist**. Both Xbox One and PlayStation 4 are region free. It is possible that this would still apply to the [censored version](http://gearnuke.com/witcher-3-comparison-censored-uncensored-reveals-almost-no-nudity/#) of the game; but due to the nature of this version, it is unlikely you will have easy access to both versions of the game, to be able to run into this problem.
- With Xbox One, saves are backed up to the cloud. Providing you connected to the internet, to allow your console to perform the backup, you could change console and still have access to your old save files.

### Computer

Computer works the same as Xbox One or PlayStation 4. Just ensure that you have not changed the installed copy of the game. If the installed directories have undergone change or corruption, you will likely require a fresh installation, which may overwrite save files.

In this instance, you can simply backup your save files, and re-add them to the new installation directory, after you have reinstalled the game.